# Selectors No overload matches this call

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

Here's my `selector.ts`

```
export interface ITestState {
  value: number;
}
export interface IReduxState {
  test: ITestState;
}
export const selectTest = (state: IReduxState) => state.test;
export const selectTestValue = createSelector(
  selectTest,
  (state: ITestState) => state.value
);
```

Ïf i try to use it in `app.component.ts`
Like so

```
  constructor(private store: Store) {
    this.vaschal$ = store.select(selectTestValue);
  }
```

I get the following error

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 9, '(mapFn: (state: object) => number): Observable<number>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'MemoizedSelector<IReduxState, number, DefaultProjectorFn<number>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: object) => number'.
      Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
        Property 'test' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'IReduxState'.
  Overload 2 of 9, '(key: never): Observable<never>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'MemoizedSelector<IReduxState, number, DefaultProjectorFn<number>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
```

angular version `11.2.4`
What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 11):

You need to inform the `Store` of the root store state:

```
constructor(private store: Store<IReduxState>) {
  this.vaschal$ = store.select(selectTestValue);
}
```

Comment: Note that this is NOT RECOMMENDED by official NgRx team https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/no-typed-global-store.md

Comment: It isn't obvious what the correct syntax is for using this.store.select so that it doesn't throw the error "No overload matches..." if the state type is removed per the recommendation.

Comment: Here is the last piece of information, update the selectTest:

    export const selectTest = createFeatureSelector<ITestState>('test');